# I am trying to finding every possible combination of adding a character to a string

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get every possible combination of adding a character to a string. For instance:

Lets say I have the string: abcdefg1234567890

I want to find every possible combination of that with the characters in the EXACT SAME order, but adding "-" in between each character. So i want my responses to include everything between:

a-bcdefg1234567890 AND ab-cdefg1234567890 AND abc-defg1234567890

Etc, as well as:
a-b-c-d-efg1234567890 AND abc-defg-1234-5678-9-0

My code already take the string and starts adding "-" bewteen characters, and then once it gets to the end, it stores that value and adds more characters from left to right. This this will give me every combination with "-" on the right side, but will not include things like:

a-b-cdefg1234567890

because after the 1'st hypen gets to the end it stays there, and starts adding more from left to right.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check itertools : https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Any specific part of it? Im looking through this and can't seem to find what im looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a coding logic problem. It doesn't have much to do with the programming language. I was looking in another SO and accidentally wound up in the Python SO instead. I don't know Python, but I can tell you how to solve the problem algorithmically.

If you want every possible combination of "dash-between-characters" and "no-dash-between characters" you'd going to output 2^(chars-1) possible strings. (If there are 4 characters in your string, there are 3 spaces between those characters.)

You have a 17-character string, so there will be 2^16 possible combinations, or 65536 different strings. That's a LOT of output strings.

You need to write code that counts from 0 to 2^(chars-1). For each value, you'll generate one of your possible output strings. The bits of that count will tell you which character pair should get a dash inserted there, and which should not.

To do that, write code that loops through every bit in the binary of the count and if the bit is 1, adds a dash to the output at that position, and if the bit is 0, does not add a dash at that position.

Pretend you only have 4 characters: 1234. There are 3 spaces for dashes, 1-2-3-4.

Say we name each of those dash positions as A, B and C:

```
1A2B3C4
```

Now lets say we assign a 1 to each letter if it gets a dash, and 0 to the letter if it does not.

Writing it out putting spaces in place of the dashes so you can see the patterns:

```
ABC     A B C
000    1 2 3 4
001    1 2 3-4
010    1 2-3 4
011    1 2-3-4
100    1-2 3 4
101    1-2 3-4
110    1-2-3 4
111    1-2-3-4
```

Each time you add another character, you add another between character spot that could contain a dash or not, so you double the total number of possible output strings.

Note that the patterns of 0s and 1s in my ABC values are the bit patterns you get when you count in binary.

### EDIT:

```
Write 2 nested loops:

Outer loop: Loop from 0 to `2^(char_count - 1)`. Let's call that value dashBits.

//Each value of dashBits will generate one of your possible output strings (in your case, one of 65536 output strings.

set outputString to an empty string.

Inner loop: Loop from left to right of the input string

   Append the current input character of your input string to the output.
   Look at the 0th bit of dashBits. If it's 1, append a dash to your output. If it's 0, don't do anything.    
   Shift dashBits 1 bit to the right.
```

Comment: I'm not working on an arduino. I am running the program in Pycharm on my Macbook pro, using python 3.  Did i put this question in the wrong section?

Comment: I messed up and wandered into the Python SO by mistake. I've edited my answer to make it non platform and non language specific.

Comment: Duncan, i appreciate your respond. I am not sure i understand it though. I am not sure i follow your math either. So if my string is 17 characters long, and the character have to remain in the same order, just adding 1 to 16 dashes between characters will give me 65,000+ strings?  That would be great if it could produce all of them.  I am using the xlsxwriter and logging them into a .xlsx file. But i am also not sure how you are doing the bits part, and then how to tell it to add -'s in the correct spots...

Comment: Yes. If you have 17 characters, there are 16 possible places to put dashes. In each place, you ether insert a dash or not. See the edit to my answer. I map out all the possible combinations when using a string of 4 characters.

Comment: As I say, I don't know Python, and I don't know what `xlsxwriter` is either. I'm telling you the algorithm to use. It's up to you to implement that algorithm in Python.

Comment: Ok, im trying to implement this, and i think i'm on the correct track. So i have my string split. But since i have letters and numbers in my string im getting confused. Lets assume my string is abc12.  So i could add numbers making it a1b2c3142.  But then how would I differentiate which characters from that to count in binary and replace with '-'?

Comment: No, I am not suggesting you build a string a1b2c3142. I was diagramming out where the dashes would go. You should loop through your input string from beginning to end. Add That character to the output string. Then use the bitwise logic I describe to decide if you should add a dash or not at that position. Repeat until the end of the input string.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I spelled out the approach in more detail.