# Get every combination of the insertion of a character in a string

Tags: python, algorithm

For reference you can also see see this question:
[I am trying to finding every possible combination of adding a character to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703276/i-am-trying-to-finding-every-possible-combination-of-adding-a-character-to-a-str)

Exactly as the other question I'm trying to get every single possible combination of the insertion of a character inside a string.

I don't understand how to implement the solution, specially how to get every combination of bits.

```
string = 'abc'

def generate_string(string):
    number_of_combinations = 2**(len(string)-1)
    str = ''
    configurations = []
    for i in range(number_of_combinations):
        #somehow get a true/false configuration of dashes
        #with abc i should have 8 possible configurations
        #i would append every configuration to configurations list
        
        for char in string:
            str = str + char
            #if the first char of configuration is true then add a '-', if false do nothing and so on for every char in the string
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  For guidance, see this guide on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @defladamouse sorry for my poor question design, the code i've written is so basic that i'm ashamed to post it.

Comment: No better way to learn

Comment: @defladamouse I added my attempt, i'm not proud of it but at least is something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```py
import itertools as itl

init = 'abcde' #Base str
inst = 'z' #Char to be inserted

for i in itl.combinations_with_replacement(init[:-1], len(init)-1):
    #Compute every combination of strs that can be computed from init
    instAfter = list(set(i)) #Remove duplicates
    newStr = '' #prepare result str
    for i in init: #loop over init str
        newStr = newStr + i #Add char to result str
        if i in instAfter: #If char in instAfter add the insert char
            newStr = newStr + inst
    print(newStr)
```

Comment: Nice ! thank you for your help. Do you also have an algorithmic version of it ? I would love to understand how it works without the use of itertools

Comment: No, but you can find an explanation of the function in the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), it shouldn't be too hard to replicate.